# How can I allow that android users only can action to login into site and not another Operating systems

Tags: php

How can I allow that android users only can action to login into site and not another operating systems in **login.php** file ?

Comment: You can't in any direct way, since you have an abstraction layer between client and server, the http protocol. Your server simply does not have any reliable means to differ between what client operating system might have made a request. You could try to guess by looking at the request headers, but those can be easily be faked if someone wants to. Actually the whole idea of the web and http is to be agnostic to the client side setup.

Comment: Knowing that `user-agent` can be spoofed--at least by nerds, you need to add extra checks such `touch` ability by Modernizr; device width and height; and screen resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

download the [mobile detect library](http://mobiledetect.net)

in your code:

```
require_once 'mobile_detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
if(!$detect->isAndroidOS()) {
    exit('OS is not Android...');
}
```